# How to load a local JSON file using JavaScript to update a select list inHTML?? (Expecting simple answers, I'm just a beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, select

This is what I want:
I want to add or remove countries from a 'countries.json' file, which stored in my local. This is just a test to understand json. Please help me.

```html
<html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <select name="countries" id="countries"></select>
 </body>
 <script src="dropdown.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to make ajax call to fetch the data and iterate it and append it in your DOM..

Comment: I told you no, I'm only 3 months old in programming field. I would be helpful if someone could explain it for me. I do think it will be very simple for you guys, that's why I asked..

Comment: @Rayon Dabre As far as I know, we can do it without Ajax right?? By using $get fn.. I'm referring to that method.

Comment: @Vishnu Vijayasankar, $.get() is just a shorthand for $.ajax()

Comment: still in doubt, but still, thanks for your response.. I will sort it out somehow..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer:
This is how I loaded json using my js:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#countries').click(function(){
        $.getJSON('dropdown.json', function(data) {
            countries = data['countries']

            $.each(countries, function(id, country) {
                $('select').append('<option value="">' + country["countryName"]+'</option>')
            })
        });
    })
})
```