# load json from localhost

Tags: javascript, json

I tried load the json from localhost but it does not work.  I searched on the web, I do not know to setup the localhost.  I saved my employee.json and my html on the desk.  I am not sure if

> $.getJSON("http://localhost/employee.json",

could  actuallly put the employee.json on the localhost? Hope someone could explained it to me.  Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>JSON with jQuery</title>
   </head>

  <body>
    <p id="demo"></p>
      <script src = "<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        $.getJSON("http://localhost/employee.json", function(data){
        $(document.body).append($('<pre>'+data+'</pre>'));
        }
      </script>

  </body>
  </html>


{
"person": [
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "firstName" : "Lokesh"
    },
    {
        "id" : 2,
        "firstName" : "bryant"
    },
    {
        "id" : 3,
        "firstName" : "kobe"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Are you on the localhost? Any errors in the console?

Comment: What is your URL for the page you are testing?

Comment: If it is on your desktop, I'm sure you have to save it in a folder in the root of localhost like localhost/employees/employees.json. Copy it to something along those lines and change the link accordingly.

Comment: @Jeff I thought the url is just http://localhost/employee.json?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/ajax-jquery-getjson.htm   This will clear you use of json

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan I actually saw this. I ran the code but i have to save the json onto localhost to actually make it work.

Comment: You just copy the json code and put this in the file and follow steps. Put all the files in the same directory

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30370452/how-to-load-a-local-json-file-using-javascript-to-update-a-select-list-inhtml more example loading country data and creating dropdown

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan I followed the tutorial and nothing shows up.  I saw the post and nothing shows up as well since I cannot load the json from the local file, i have to sort of put onto the localhost

Comment: $(function() { }); put your code between these.

Comment: use employee.json, instead of http://localhost/employee.json

Comment: @DeepakDholiyan — Why? The `<script>` that tries to modify the body appears after the body start tag

Comment: @alex007 — Aside from needing a webserver, your first script element is wrong. `src` takes a URL, not a whole script tag.

Comment: @alex007 — Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the Console. The error messages are useful.

Comment: @alex007 I asked what the url is for your HTML because there usually is a folder that you are storing things in. http://localhost/test/index.html. know this could help to locate where to point the $.getJSON() function. Also, as suggested, open the inspect elements and look at the Console in order to see errors. If they are there than add that to this posting.

Answer (score 1):

In order for you to make an HTTP request over the network to `localhost`, you need to be running an HTTP server on your computer and configure it to listen on the `localhost` network interface (which every HTTP server will do by default).

There are a wide selection out there. Apache HTTPD is the industry standard. Many versions of Windows come with a version of IIS built-it. PHP includes a Simple Web Server feature for development. JavaScript developers often use Node.js to build a server (typically either as a Grunt or Gulp plugin if they are developing a static site or based around Express.js if they are writing server side JavaScript).

You need to install one, configure it to serve your JSON file for the URL you want, and then run it.